# Invoking java based webservices from ColdFusion application: coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException:[coldfusion.runtime.AbortException : null]

Tags: java, web-services, coldfusion, jax-ws, coldfusion-9

We have a legacy coldfusion (web) application which makes some calls to a webservice API implemented in coldfusion itself.We are currently planning to migrate all these API webservices to java based API webservices (JAX-WS).

I have configured the endpoint url in the Application.cfc file  of the coldfusion web application to the endpoint of the java based API webservice.

But, now the service invocation is failing with the exception below. 
I have never worked with coldfusion code before so I am not sure 
when this exception is thrown. Any help appreciated!

---

```
<soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException: [coldfusion.runtime.AbortException : null]</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:stackTrace xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">
    coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException: [coldfusion.runtime.AbortException : null]   
              at        coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFComponentSkeleton.__createCFCInvocationException(CFComponentSkeleton.java:733)     
              at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFComponentSkeleton.__invoke(CFComponentSkeleton.java:671) 
              at CMC.changeEmail(/var/www/CMC/html/CMC.cfc) 
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
              at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

CFC code for invocation:

```
<cfif LoginResult AND VARIABLES.AllowEmail>
          <cfset StartTime = getTickCount() />

            <cftry>
            <cfinvoke webservice="#VARIABLES.EmailWSDL#" method="changeEmail" returnvariable="returnStruct">
            <cfinvokeargument name="Email" value="#ARGUMENTS.Email#" />
            <cfinvokeargument name="NewEmail" value="#ARGUMENTS.NewEmail#" />
            <cfinvokeargument name="Password" value="#ARGUMENTS.Password#" />
            <cfinvokeargument name="FirstName" value="#ARGUMENTS.FirstName#" />
            <cfinvokeargument name="LastName" value="#ARGUMENTS.LastName#" />

            </cfinvoke>

            <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfif isDefined("CFCATCH")>
            <cfinvoke method="LogError">
            <cfinvokeargument name="LogID" value="#myLogID#">
            <cfinvokeargument name="Error" value="#duplicate(CFCATCH)#">
            </cfinvoke>
            </cfif>
            <cfinclude template="_error.cfm" />
            </cfcatch>

            </cftry>
```

the value of VARIABLES.EmailWSDL is set in the Application.cfc file as below:

```
 <cfset APPLICATION.EmailWSDL = "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/TESTAPI/http/Email/EmailProxy?wsdl" />
```

THe Webservice wsdl (SOAP xml) scaled down to show only 1 message and corresponding tags:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:esb="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:impl="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

```
  <wsdl:part name="changeEmailReturn" type="apachesoap:Map"/>
```

```
  <wsdl:part name="Email" type="xsd:string"/>

  <wsdl:part name="NewEmail" type="xsd:string"/>

  <wsdl:part name="Password" type="xsd:string"/>

  <wsdl:part name="FirstName" type="xsd:string"/>

  <wsdl:part name="LastName" type="xsd:string"/>
```

```
  <wsdl:operation name="changeEmail" parameterOrder="Email NewEmail LoginTokenUUID OpenID eSAN Password FirstName LastName">

     <wsdl:input message="impl:changeEmailRequest" name="changeEmailRequest"/>

     <wsdl:output message="impl:changeEmailResponse" name="changeEmailResponse"/>

     <wsdl:fault message="impl:CFCInvocationException" name="CFCInvocationException"/>

  </wsdl:operation>
```

```
  <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>



  <wsdl:operation name="changeEmail">

     <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

     <wsdl:input name="changeEmailRequest">

        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://DefaultNamespace" use="encoded"/>

     </wsdl:input>

     <wsdl:output name="changeEmailResponse">

        <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://DefaultNamespace" use="encoded"/>

     </wsdl:output>

     <wsdl:fault name="CFCInvocationException">

        <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="CFCInvocationException" namespace="http://DefaultNamespace" use="encoded"/>

     </wsdl:fault>

  </wsdl:operation>
```

```
  <wsdl:port binding="impl:email.cfcSoapBinding" name="email.cfc">

     <wsdlsoap:address location="http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/TESTAPI/http/Email/EmailProxy"/>

  </wsdl:port>
```

Comment: Please show us the ColdFusion code that is calling your web service.

Comment: The webservice (SOAP) XML would be helpful too.

Comment: Added Coldfusion code  and Application.cfc configuration. SOAP wsdl is too big, but I'll try to put up a scaled down version.